# How to find compatible RAM for second laptop DIMM slot

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, compatibility, ddr

I bought a laptop that has 2 DIMM slots, it shipped with a 16 GB stick in one of these slots, but I want to upgrade it and get another 16 GB stick without sacrificing my existing one.

I did a little bit of digging first to see if it used any off the shelf RAM but no such luck, buying an identical second stick is not an option.

Is it fine to use RAM from a different manufacturer?

How do I find out which RAM I should buy that will be safely compatible?

What are the key specifications that need to match up between my RAM stick and the RAM stick I would buy. How do I find out exactly what these specifications are for my current stick (I tried looking up the model number, they don't have it catalogued online, so I'm gonna need software to dig up the details).

Is it really so simple that if the slot supports DDR4-2666 MHz (according to the laptop's specification page) that any DDR4-2666 MHz stick of the same form factor will do the trick without problems?

Can I trust RAM manufacturer websites (like Kingston and Crucial) that if they claim certain sticks to be compatible with my laptop that it will work flawlessly in the second slot with my stock stick in the first one?

Comment: As you mentioned, Kingston and Crucial databases are good... to my own knowledge and from their online reputations. There are also apps you can download from them that will check your memory and find compatible RAM.

Comment: You also need to find out if the motherboard supports more than 16 GB of RAM. Just because the motherboard has an empty slot, that doesn't necessarily mean you can add another stick of RAM.

Comment: @Blackwood naturally it does.

Comment: @Cestarian I'm not sure why you say "naturally". If you checked the motherboard specs and they say it supports 32 GB, fair enough. If you mean that because it has two slots that can each take 16 GB then it must be able to support 32 GB, that is not necessarily the case. Motherboards can have a limit on the amount of RAM they can support that is less than the sum of the maximum RAM for each slot.

Comment: @Blackwood what I meant was that that was never part of the question, i.e. we assume that it does. (And yes, of course I checked)